# Precision of a Vision/CoreML Object Recognizer in Swift

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, keras, coreml

I just wanted to start learning the incredible frameworks apple supported to us and as I browsed through the web I came across a very basic question no one addresses so far: How precise can a CoreML object recognizer be? Meaning how exact can an CoreML app possible differentiate?

**For Example**:

If I would try to create a car model recognizer, will it be able to tell a VW Golf 3 from VW Golf 4?

Will it be able to differentiate between different choppers(motorcyles) which only differ slightly?

Can it tell the difference between a beer and an usual soda bottle?

Answer (score 2):

This completely depends on the model you design and how you train it. It doesn't have much to do with Core ML itself, since Core ML doesn't know anything about cars or motorcycles or soda bottles. That knowledge is captured by your model. If you can train a model that can do such things then Core ML can probably run it.

The easiest way to find out if a model can tell apart a VW Golf 3 from a 4 is to gather a whole bunch of images of both types of cars, and use [Turi Create](https://github.com/apple/turicreate) (open source from Apple) to train such a model.

As for how accurate such a model can be, the only way to find out is to build one and train it and then evaluate it. Note that image classifiers (the type of model you're talking about here) on the ILSVRC challenge get over 95% accuracy, which is considered to be about human-level performance.

So given enough data,a well-chosen model architecture, and a proper training procedure, you can probably approximate the accuracy level of an average human expert in the problem domain you've chosen.